# Podcast app occupies all my local phone storage

Tags: 8.1, storage, podcast

I own a htc 8S which has very limited internal storage where 3.x GB of 4 are already used by the OS itself, and now the Podcast app owns 600 MB of them, leaving only some MB which will never ever again let me install any OS update.

To be clear, there are no stored pod casts at all -- it crashed while downloading to the internal storage because regardless of the enabled setting "store pod casts to SD card" they temporarily got stored on the phone directly.

Storage sense tool says:

```
Phone -> Podcasts : 0 bytes
SD card -> Podcasts : 0 bytes
Phone -> APPS+GAMES -> Podcasts -> Installation : 5.89 MB
Phone -> APPS+GAMES -> Podcasts -> Data : 600 MB
```

There is no way to either move the entire Podcast app to the SD card nor to uninstall the Podcast app at all -- HELP!

Answer (score 1):

If you can neither open the podcast app / delete downloaded or temporary files nor move everything to the sd card I guess your only option left is to do a hard reset and clean up your phone that way.

Comment: I'm still in hope that this is NOT the answer. Can't they or don't want the idiots at Microsoft do anything right?

Comment: You can always contact Microsoft support directly and post suggestions on http://windowsphone.uservoice.com but for now I'm afraid there seems to be no other way considering this problem apparently not being very common.

Comment: So after the phone told me 5 times a day that there is a new update (which of course I cannot install due too less space) I decided to do a hard reset. Did a cloud backup and selected it to be restored -- all contacts gone, every history just contains numbers instead of names. I HATE YOU MICROSOFT!

Comment: Have you finished reinstalling ask those apps through the store after restoring the backup?

Comment: Yes, I waited an amount of time. After the restore mostly everything LOOKED as before (custom lock screen, custom background, transparent and smaller buttons). Now I just did a reboot in hope it would help anything, but NOW everything is nearly as a total reinstall. Nothing looks like it was my phone any more. Frustation just DOUBLED now!

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded and installed tha windows phone  app for os x and I was able to detect over  2Gb of hidden  podcasts that I could not  deleted on the phone itself

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and installed the Windows Phone app for OS X and I was able to delete over 2GB of hidden Podcasts that I could not delete on the Phone itself.